# ASP.NET Core MVC Путь древовидной структуры

Tags: c#, asp-net-core-mvc

Необходимо сделать такой путь в контроллере

[image: Путь в Views]

Чтобы в адресной строке отображалось как .../portfolio/love_story/album1 , так и  .../portfolio/love_story/

Сейчас контроллер выглядит так

```
public class portfolioController : Controller

{

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

И я не понимаю, как сделать так, чтобы это работало. Пробовал сделать контроллер love_story, но это не работает. Так понимаю, мне нужно нужно прописать путь в Startup.cs? Но тут тоже не совсем понимаю, как это сделать. К слову, мне нужно просто, чтобы страницы отображались.

Comment: Вообще, чтобы понять, как работает маршрутизация в ASP.NET Core, можно почитать эту статью: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Однако, возникает вопрос: насколько Вы в принципе знакомы с ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 0):

Самым простым будет сделать так:

```
public class portfolioController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("love_story/album1")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Еще о маршрутизации можно почитать здесь: https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet_webapi/3.1.php